# Unity Path Generation On 2D Grid

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid

```
      roadTopStartX = Random.Range(5, 10);  // Path's x position which creation begins
      roadTopStartY = Random.Range(8, 12);  // Path's y position which creation begins
    
     roadTopLength = Random.Range(4, 9); // Path's length

     for (int i = 0; i < roadTopLength; i++)
     {
         GameObject tile = GameObject.Find("Tile" + (roadTopStartX + i) + " " + roadTopStartY); //I created grid whose tile's name Tile X Y like Tile 0 0
         GameObject road =  Instantiate(roadPrefab, tile.transform.position, tile.transform.rotation);
         
         road.name = "Road"+ " " + (roadTopStartX + i) + " " + roadTopStartY;
         
         
         roads.Add(road);

     }
```

It is how i create random path on 2d grid, do you know better solution because when thinks become more complex gameobject.find becomes suffer for me

Comment: There are many ways to create Random Paths. You may watch some Videos about this topic. One way would be using Perlin noise for Example. One Videot about this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-qsKfzLS7Q

Comment: If yourain concern is the `Find` .. why not when you generate your grid store all the tiles in a `GameObject[,]` and directly access them via `var tile = theArray[roadTopStartX + i, roadTopStartY];`

Answer (score 0):

i found a more reliable solution: (thanks to derHugo)

```
 public GameObject findTile(int x,int y)
{
    GameObject findTilex = GameObject.Find("Tile" + (tileX + x) + " " + 
    (tileY + y));

    return findTilex;
}
```

Example how i get neighbour tiles

```
public void getNeighbours()
{
    if (findTile(0, 1) != null)
    {
        upper = findTile(0, 1);
        
    }

    if (findTile(0, -1) != null)
    {
        below = findTile(0, -1);

    }

    if (findTile(1, 0) != null)
    {
        right = findTile(1, 0);

    }

    if (findTile(-1, 0) != null)
    {
        left = findTile(-1, 0);

    }

    if (findTile(1, 1) != null)
    {
        rightCrossTop = findTile(1, 1);

    }

    if (findTile(1, -1) != null)
    {
        rightCrossUnder = findTile(1, -1);

    }

    if (findTile(-1, 1) != null)
    {
        leftCrossTop = findTile(-1, 1);

    }

    if (findTile(-1, -1) != null)
    {
        leftCrossBottom = findTile(-1, -1);

    }

}
```